# How would I annotate this .net Type to serialise/deserialise to/from the following XML, using System.Xml.Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xmlserializer

The type:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Fred { get; set; }
}
```

The instance

```
Foo x = new Foo { Bar = "Hi", Fred = "hey yourself" };
```

The XML:

```
<Foo>
   <Bar>Hi</Bar>
   <John>                         <!-- Note extra layer -->
       <Fred>hey there</Fred>
   </John>
</Foo>
```

Note the extra `John` tag, but without create a special type for `John`. If I cannot annotate it, what how can I programmatically control the serialisation process.

Comment: where did john tag come from? do you mean you want to nest a tag with some other custom tag?

Comment: That's the question I want the extra tag.

Comment: I think you should use XmlDocument and write your own code instead of using XmlSerializer. that maybe your last choice

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Foo x = new Foo { Bar = "Hi", Fred = "hey yourself" };
            //<Foo>
            //   <Bar>Hi</Bar>
            //   <John>                         <!-- Note extra layer -->
            //       <Fred>hey there</Fred>
            //   </John>
            //</Foo>

            XElement foo = new XElement("Foo", new object[] {
                new XElement("Bar", x.Bar),
                new XElement("John", new XElement("Fred", x.Fred))
            });

        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public string Fred { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm already using System.Xml.Serialization and my question is just an example of a much bigger set of types I'm serialising. Can I hook this into the System.Xml.Serialization process?

Comment: You would have to write a custom serializer.   I never have wrote one.  The standard serializer enumerates through the classes and add "John" where is doesn't exist.in you class Foo.  I don't know how a serilizer can do that.